# Trying to display alertView using if/else statements in iOS

Tags: ios, if-statement, uialertview

I am writing an application where I wish to display an alertView that shows a different message depending on whether certain circumstances have taken place.  If none of the circumstances match, than no alert should be displayed, and the rest of the application should be processed.  My problem is that I am not sure how to do this.  I have the following code:

```
 - (void) methodThatIsCalled {

             NSString *msg;

             if (blah) {

                 msg = @"Message A";

             }

             else if (blah blah) {

                 msg = @"Message B";

             }

             else if (blah blah blah) {

                 msg = @"Message C";

             }

             //Here is where I want to display the Alert code
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];

             else {

                   Do rest of the application....


             }

      }
```

Can anyone show me how to do this such that I have only one block of code of displaying the Alert, and dynamically pass the message string to the alert, and do nothing if none of the clauses match?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: make sure you release alert, otherwise its a memory leak.

Comment: Even if I am using ARC?

Comment: ARC..then Ignore...Happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void) showAlertWithTitle: (NSString*) title message: (NSString*) message
{
    UIAlertView* alert= [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title message: message
                                                   delegate: NULL cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles: NULL] autorelease];
    [alert show];

}
```

//In your function:

```
if (blah) {
    [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"Message A"];
} 
 else if (blah blah) {
    [self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error"  message:@"Message B"];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change to

```
NSString *msg = nil;
```

then add an if

```
if (msg) { // If there is a message
    //Here is where I want to display the Alert code
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                              message:msg
                                              delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
} else {
    ... // Rest of application
}
```